# Smartpy transfer contract balance to an address

Tags: transactions, smartpy, contract, transfer

I'm trying to figure out how to withdraw money from the contract within a smartpy entrypoint, and test the result in my scenario.

When I test the entrypoint:

```
  @sp.entry_point
  def withdraw(self, amount):
    sp.set_type(amount, sp.TMutez)
    sp.sender.transfer(amount)
```

I don't see the balance change in the scenario after the endpoint successfully executed when I check the contract.balance with sp.verify or scenario.show(c1.balance) or scenario.verify(c1.balance == sp.tez(...))

This was a solidity translation and the expression seems to work and run okay but it's not doing what I expect.

How can I withdraw from the contract or transfer contract balance to an account address in my smartpy entrypoint?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is simply:

```
@sp.entry_point
def withdraw(self, amount):
    sp.set_type(amount, sp.TMutez)
    sp.send(sp.sender, amount)
```

The solidity translation tool I used didn't handle this properly